# Allow Evosuite to write files during test generation

Tags: java, jna, evosuite

Im currently trying to get Evosuite to work with [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). Consider the following basic example:

```
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

public class Example {
    public static int foo(int x) {
        IntByReference c = new IntByReference(x);

        if (c.getValue() == 100) {
            return 100;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Im running Evosuite from the command line with these options:

```
java32 -jar evosuite.jar -projectCP "src;E:\evosuite\test\lib\jna-5.2.0.jar" -class Example -criterion branch
```

Evosuite wont reach 100% branch coverage (only the trivial 33%), but notifies me with this message after the timeout:

```
* Permissions denied during test execution:
  - java.io.FilePermission:
         write C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--2025216854: 1
```

I found out that JNA needs to write some temp files in order to work, but Evosuite will block any atempt of file writing during test generation. I understand that this is a reasonable policy in most cases because you dont want Evosuite to write random files to your disk while generating tests for a `saveFile()` function, but in my case this shouldn't be a problem.

Is there a way to tell Evosuite to allow file writing during test generation or a different approach to generate tests for java programms using the JNA library?

Comment: See https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/985 it may be possible to manually run that version of JNA to generate the files; once they are there, they do not need to be re-generated.

Comment: To add to Daniel's comment: extract the `jnidispatch` file specific to your environment, move it to some directory of your choosing and set `-Djna.boot.library.path=` to point to that directory, and set `jna.nosys=true` to make sure JNA tries to load it. I haven't tested, but perhaps this will prevent JNA from attempting to extract the native dispatcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to run JNA without the need of writing temporary files thanks to [cubrr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996081/cubrr).

- copy the system specific `jnidispatch.[dll, ...]` file to a *folder*
- add `-Djna.boot.library.path=folder -Djna.nounpack=true` to the command

Note: the `jna.boot.library.path` should only point to the containig folder, **do not** write  <s>`folder/jnidispatch`</s>.

---

### Solution to the initial question:

Setting the evosuite option **`-Dsandbox=false`** will remove most restrictions for test generation and finally allowed me to generate my tests!